# Execute sql command after opening connection and before closing

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-core, ef-core-2.1

Given: ASP.NET Core 2.1 WebApi, EF Core 2.1, SQL Server 2008 R2 legacy database.

Question: What`s the best way to execute sql command "EXECUTE AS " right after every connection opening and "REVERT" just before closing connection?

Comment: Which EF Core version? EF Core 3 has interceptors and global filters that weren't available in previous versions

Comment: EF Core 2.1, edited question

Comment: Interceptors were added in EF Core 3.0, eg [IDbConnectionInterceptor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.diagnostics.idbconnectioninterceptor?view=efcore-3.0)

Comment: Why do you want to use `EXECUTE AS` though? Why not just use an account with the correct permissions? Or are you trying to implement a multi-tenant system? In that case there are better options, eg [global query filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/filters) can be used to filter the data by customer/company/user

Comment: Sounds great! I should consider update my EF to 3.0 if it's possible. Can you provide an example in answer section?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos it's because the DB has it's own legacy logic hard coded in stored procedures so I can't change it. To put it simple, I just need to change user context before execution of any SQL to make DB aplly all its logic on the impersonated user, not on the initially connected user. And before closing connection to revert it back.

Answer (score 1):

Try wrapping the connection opening and closing in a wrapper method along with the call to 'EXECUTE AS';  then use that wrapper call in your code.  Incidentally there are severe restrictions on the use of 'EXECUTE AS'.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/execute-as-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Thank you! I applied your solution in other project, because DB is the same. There I have connection factory class, and my custom wrapper class applied there, in one place. But in that project I have no particular single place to change or I can't see it :)